# Starting module shell command from python subprocess module

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, environment-modules

I'm trying to run vnc server, but in order to do it first I need to run 'module load vnc'.

If I call `which module` in loaded bash shell then the command in not found is the PATH but in the same time it's available. It looks like the command is built-in.

In other words it looks like I need to execute two commands at once `module load vnc;vncserver :8080 -localhost` and I'm writing script to start it from python.
I have tried different variants with `subprocess.Popen` like

```
subprocess.Popen('module load vnc;vncserver :8080 -localhost', shell=True)
```

which returns `127` exit code or `command not found`.

```
subprocess.Popen('module load vnc;vncserver :8080 -localhost', shell=False)
```

showing

```
File <path>/subprocess.py line 621, in \__init__    
                                   errread, errwrite)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

If I specify `shell=True`, it executes from `/bin/sh` but I need it from `/bin/bash`.

Specifying `executable='/bin/bash'` doesn't help as it loads new bash shell but it starts as string but not as process, i.e. I see in `ps` list exactly the same command I would like to start.

Would you please advise how to do start this command from subprocess module? Is it possible to have it started with `shell=False`?

Comment: Does `module load vnc` need to be run in the same shell / command as `vncserver`? Why do you need `/bin/bash`? `/bin/sh` is almost certainly a symlink to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: You need a shell in order to execute multiple commands.  You can try something like `'bash -c "module load vnc; vncserver :8080 -localhost"'` but it's probably not really the right way to do it.

Comment: @tripleee that's what the `shell` and `executable` arguments he's talking about do

Comment: @agf yes but if he needs the same bash he can use shell=false and use bash -c '...' as the single command to run.

Comment: @agf, yes, it should be run in the same shell. You are right, /bin/sh is symlink to bash. I think then it shouldn't be the difference.

Comment: Did you try `subprocess.Popen('bash -c "module load vnc; vncserver :8080 -localhost"')`?

Comment: @triplee, I have tried this command `subprocess.Popen("/bin/bash -c 'module load vnc;vncserver :8080 -localhost'", shell=True)`. In result it shows `/bin/bash: module: command not found`.
If you specify in the same command shell=False then appears 
`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.` message.

Comment: @yart : maybe the path to your `module` command is only set in a your .bashrc file, and it may be not loaded by Popen.

Comment: @eryksun, thank you but there is no such file as `/etc/profile.d/modules.sh`

Comment: @eryksun, there are no such files in both locations you have specified.

Comment: The proper replacement for ‘which‘ is called ‘type‘. What does ‘type -all module‘ print for you?

Comment: @triplee, thank you. It shows module function with the content similar to what eryksun wrote about the file. Eval command calls <path>/modules.tcl file.

Comment: @eryksun, there is such variable but there is no bash in init directory. There is $modules_shell variable which is bash.

Comment: @eryksun, I just tried and at least it shows module help command which means syntax should be checked.

Comment: @yart I am struck some where like here.. i have to load clearcase module using module load clearcase and then i need to execute clearcase commands using cleartool.. but i ve encountered the same problem. Did you solve your problem now ? If yes can you tell me ?

Comment: @SravanKGhantasala, have you tried the code from accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, a failed attempt yart.. But thats ok i m directly adding path of clearcase to my system path and using it.. :P a way around can say... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment Modules usually just modifies a couple environment variables for you. It's usually possible to skip the `module load whatever` step altogether and just not depend on those modules. I recommend

```
subprocess.Popen(['/possibly/path/to/vncserver', ':8080', '-localhost'], 
                 env={'WHATEVER': 'you', 'MAY': 'need'})
```

instead of loading the module at all.

If you do insist on using this basic method, then you want to start bash yourself with `Popen(['bash',...`.

Comment: thank you, Mike. I was also thinking directly to to start vncserver but I couldn't find where vncserver file is and it's unknown how environment is extended after specifying vnc module.

Comment: @yart, In that case `Popen(["bash", "-c", "module load vnc; vncserver :8080 -localhost"])` or whatever might be your best bet.

Comment: Mike, thank you. This command returns 127 exit code, but if I specify "-ci" instead of just "-c" it works. Why it works with interactive shell only?

Comment: @yart, it's possible that the code to define the `module` builtin is in `bashrc` rather than `bash_profile`/`profile`, so `module` was never defined in a non-interactive session. Personally, I usually have my personal `~/.bash_profile` execute my `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with `shell=False`, just split this into two `Popen` calls.

```
subprocess.check_call('module load vnc'.split())
subprocess.Popen('vncserver :8080 -localhost'.split())
```

Comment: `module` is likely the Environment Modules shell builtin, not an executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `module` from a Python script. The `module` command is provided by the environment-modules software, which also provides a `python.py` initialization script.

Evaluating this script in a Python script enables the `module` python function. If environment-modules is installed in `/usr/share/Modules`, you can find this script at `/usr/share/Modules/init/python.py`.

Following code enables `module` python function:

```
import os
exec(open('/usr/share/Modules/init/python.py').read())
```

Thereafter you can load your module and start your application:

```
module('load', 'vnc')
subprocess.Popen(['vncserver', ':8080', '-localhost'])
```