# Using python subprocess with module load

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I'm currently using Python 2.7 on a unix environment.
I need to run R scripts in my python scripts but I can't manage to make it work because my R module needs to be loaded before (using "module load")

Here's my python script :

```
import os
import subprocess as sp

os.system('module load R/3.2.3')
out = sp.check_output(['Rscript','test.R'], universal_newlines=True)
```

I keep having the same error : "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Any idea ?
I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123181/starting-module-shell-command-from-python-subprocess-module) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047336/how-to-run-command-module-avail-using-subprocess) but couldn't make it work.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Post the entire stack trace. Also be careful where the scripts are located, both the python and R ones, for easiness you could place them all in the same directory.

Comment: Is test.R in your working directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what "module load" actually does is set some environment variables in the calling shell.  So when you do this:

```
os.system('module load R/3.2.3')
```

Python creates a process, runs `/bin/sh` in it, and passes that command to the shell.  The module environment variables are set in that shell.  Then that shell exits--job done!

The environment variables do not--and cannot--propagate back to the Python process.  So when you do this:

```
sp.check_output(['Rscript','test.R'])
```

It's totally irrelevant that you ran `module load` before.

So how can you fix this?  Well, one possibility would be to explicitly specify the path to `Rscript`:

```
sp.check_output(['/your/full/path/to/Rscript','test.R'])
```

Another would be to combine your commands:

```
sp.check_output('module load R/3.2.3 && Rscript test.R', shell=True)
```

Finally, you could simply run `module load` before running your Python script in the first place.  The environment variables it sets can propagate all the way to the R invocation within Python.

By the way, it is possible to invoke R directly from Python: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/introduction.html